# No search results using just the first letter of Make

Tags: sql

Performing a query for a make that starts with F, but now data comes up. I know I have data in vehicle table.

```
Select Vehicle_ID, Vehicle_Make, Vehicle_Model, Vehicle_Year 
From Vehicle 
Where Vehicle_Make like ('F');
```

Trying to get query results with the makers of cars that start with "F".

Answer (score 1):

you should read some documentation on the like operator, eg
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

you'll know then that the query you're trying to write is

```sql
    SELECT Vehicle_ID, Vehicle_Make, Vehicle_Model, Vehicle_Year
    FROM Vehicle
    WHERE Vehicle_Make LIKE ('F%');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
Select Vehicle_ID, Vehicle_Make, Vehicle_Model, Vehicle_Year 
From Vehicle 
Where Vehicle_Make like 'F%';
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).